# Delete Vertex by clicking clontext menu of vertex

Tags: wpf, graph-sharp

I have added context menu to vertex By following code

```
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type graphsharp:VertexControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type graphsharp:VertexControl}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <Border.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
                                            <MenuItem x:Name="miDelete" Click="miAdd_Click" Header="Delete" />
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </Border.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Vertex}" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

Added events to code page by

```
    Public Sub miAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

    End Sub
    Public Sub ContextMenu_Opened(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
```

But how can i get the id or value of vertex to delete it

Answer (score -1):

sample in C# - I think rewrite to vb will have no problem...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GraphSharp_Controls:VertexControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="v_ContextMenuClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete this vertex" CommandParameter="{x:Static SampleProject:ContextCommands.REMOVE}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/del.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                ...
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- where 'ContextCommands' is just my pre-defined enums... -->
    ...
```

and this is click handler

```
private void v_ContextMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)sender;
VertexControl vc = null;
if (mi != null){
    vc = (VertexControl)((ContextMenu)mi.Parent).PlacementTarget;
    //my own class inherited from GraphSharp.Controls.VertexControl
    //you can use what you have directly
    PocVertex pv = (PocVertex)vc.Vertex;
    //same thing with graph class
    //graph is stored globally
    PocGraph gg = App.vm.Graph;

    switch ((ContextCommands)mi.CommandParameter){
        case ContextCommands.REMOVE:
            gg.RemoveVertex(pv);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
e.Handled = true;
```

}

fyi - handler function must be stored under xaml.cs code to be visible.
hope this helps...